# how sorting do sorting in angular js using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to sort column in ascending and descending order when user click on header of each column .I have list in which header is placed on top .I want to sort my column using **"^"** and **"V"** key .I make a directive to sort my column but it not work .First my image is not display this image **"V" and "^"**(not display) and second when I click on header column it not sorting the table in ascending and descending order.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/wSwyUGOyazlvuA8SxwEe?p=preview

```
.directive('sortHeader', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '^headerRow',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'label': '@',
            'sortstring': '&sortExp',
            'idx': '@index'
        },
        templateUrl: 'sort-header.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, headerCtrl) {
            headerCtrl.addSortHeader(scope);
            scope.reverse = false;
            element.on('click', function(){
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;
                    headerCtrl.select(scope);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Template**

```
.run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('sort-header.html', '<button class="buttonHeader button button-clear button-dark fntandbg headerbtnclass columnHeaderFontfamily"><i class="icon"  ng-if="label==\'Account Name\'" ng-class="{\'ion-arrow-down-b\': reverse, \'ion-arrow-up-b\': !reverse}"></i> <strong>{{label}}</strong></button>');
}).
```

I am able to add icon on header with text but not able sort
update **plunker**
http://plnkr.co/edit/wSwyUGOyazlvuA8SxwEe?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker doesn't load.

Comment: let me check and update you

Comment: there is problem in plunker server ...!! soon it will works

Comment: Now plunker is working fine.http://plnkr.co/edit/wSwyUGOyazlvuA8SxwEe?p=preview

Comment: updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wSwyUGOyazlvuA8SxwEe?p=preview

Comment: Still need help with this?